# Microsoft graph 401 Unauthorized error while request users/{user_id}/calendars

Tags: php, azure, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

Trying request calendars list, but get 401 Unauthorized error. I can get users, can create new user, but can't get or create calendars.

I'm using these libraries:

[thephpleague/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client)

[msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

get token via Client Credentials Grant method, access without a user.

```
$this->oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
            'clientId'                => $config['oauth_app_id'],
            'clientSecret'            => $config['oauth_app_password'],
            'redirectUri'             => $config['oauth_redirect_uri'],
            'urlAuthorize'            => $config['oauth_authority'].$config['tenantID'].$config['oauth_authorize_endpoint'],
            'urlAccessToken'          => $config['oauth_authority'].$config['tenantID'].$config['oauth_token_endpoint'],
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
            'scopes'                  => $config['oauth_scopes']
        ]);

$newToken = $this->oauthClient->getAccessToken('client_credentials', [
                    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
                ]);

$graph = new \Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($newToken);
```

//This works

```
$users = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/users/')
            ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
            ->execute();
```

And this works

```
$users = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/users/{user_id}')
            ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
            ->execute();
```

But this not works

```
 $calendars = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/users/{user_id}/calendars')
                ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\Calendar::class)
                ->execute();
```

In apps.dev.microsoft.com and in Azure portal trying sets all permissions this not helps. In [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) same result.

Comment: Can you check what scopes your application *actually* has, by looking at your access token and the scp claim in https://jwtinspect.azurewebsites.net/ please?  Does it have the Calendars.Read permission? Can you also provide the full error message including client-request-id and the timestamp, please?

Comment: Spin up Fiddler and run the request through it. You will get a far better picture of the actual request being made instead of relying on what you believe the libraries are doing.

Comment: I checked on   jwtinspect.azurewebsites.net, it shows me this:
    roles: [
      "Mail.ReadWrite",
      "User.ReadWrite.All",
      "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
      "Calendars.Read",
      "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
      "MailboxSettings.Read",
      "Contacts.ReadWrite",
      "User.Invite.All",
      "Directory.Read.All",
      "User.Read.All",
      "Mail.Read",
      "Calendars.ReadWrite",
      "Mail.Send",
      "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
      "Contacts.Read",
      "Member.Read.Hidden"
     ],

Comment: Full error message: 
{ "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": { "request-id": "eba74ab9-4d22-437c-a8a9-15be3c9500b3", "date": "2017-11-07T07:40:18" } } }

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft
tried use clear cURL without a library, get same error

Comment: All I can think of is to double check the permissions. Make sure you are looking up the correct app (registration) and then ensure you have all the calendar permissions checked. How are you testing with Graph Explorer? With your user account? If this is the case - check your permissions with the  "modify permissions" link.

Comment: I checked permissions many times, yes I tested with my user account, all permissions set true. I can get user list, can use user_id for getting information about one user, but can't get calendars. So registration of app is correct, otherwise I could not get user data

Comment: It turned out that if you select a personal account, then you can create calendars and events, but you can not create users, and vice versa, if you select a work account or school account, then you can create users, but you can't create calendars for them. At least using the documentation does not work.