# MS Graph External User 401 Unathorized

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'll try and summarize my scenario after browsing similar questions:

1. Azure tenant with a native application and an admin user account. Access from the application to MS Graph API as the admin account works.
2. I have an outlook.com account and using MS Graph Explorer works to read email.
3. I used the admin account to invite the external outlook.com account. I added this external user to the application's users, to the O365 subscription license, I double checked the same granted permissions I see from Graph Explorer, including `Mail.Read` et al. Verified the token has those permissions.
4. I even tried making the external user a global administrator to test, but... hitting the MS Graph API from the native app using the outlook.com creds yields a `401 Unauthorized`.
5. If I copy the full URI from my native app and paste into MS Graph it works.

This is our native and web app calling code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var requestUri = $"{MSGraphUtils.GraphResource}/{MSGraphUtils.VERSION}/{request}";
var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

`requestUri` is complete with token and `{request}` is appended to be:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders` or `me/mailfolders/{id}/messages`.

Instead of `/me`, I've also tried `/users/{id|UPN}`.

If I send only `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` then the response is the correct basic profile, but as soon as `/mailfolders` or `/messages` is appended I get a `401 Unauthorized`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "551340c6-1753-41d5-bc1a-e3ccdbc98e00",
      "date": "2018-05-24T13:48:23"
    }
  }
}
```

If I copy the entire requestUri with token and paste it directly into Microsoft Graph Explorer, it will work with `/mailfolders`.

Also adding the token `scp` with granted permissions:

```
Calendars.ReadWrite 
Contacts.ReadWrite 
Files.ReadWrite.All 
Mail.Read 
Mail.ReadWrite 
Notes.ReadWrite.All 
People.Read 
Sites.Read.All 
Tasks.ReadWrite 
User.Read 
User.ReadBasic.All 
User.ReadWrite
```

The token is obtained:

```
public static string Authority = "https://login.windows.net/common";
public static string GraphResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
public static string ReturnUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

public static Task Authenticate(Account account)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);

    if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
         authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

    var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);

    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResource, CLIENT_ID, new Uri(ReturnUri), platformParams);

    if (result != null)
    {
       account.token = result.AccessToken;
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code you're using and the actual responses you're receiving. Describing what your code does is always open to interpretation while the code is much less so. Including both is super valuable for the community when it comes to parsing out what is happening without a lot of context.

Comment: How are you obtaining your token?

Comment: This code is working just fine for using an admin account to scan MS Graph for file streams. It's ONLY after i try to authenticate with an external guest outlook.com account i've invited into our tenant application and try to access /mailfolders or /messages does it fails 401.

Comment: This is a very similar question posted: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121350/microsoft-graph-401-unauthorized-error-while-request-users-user-id-calendars?rq=1)

Comment: Are you able to access this user's mailbox via OWA? Are you sure they _have_ a provisioned mailbox in your Exchange Online instance? I suspect they do not.

Comment: It's just an outlook.com email test account with data. I can access this with MS Graph Explorer. I can literally copy our native app generated URL with token that gets the 401 and paste it directly into MS Graph and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When a user authenticates against *your* tenant, you only have access to the data controlled by your tenant. In other words, if `jdoe@outlook.com` authenticates against `yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com` tenant, you don't gain access to their `outlook.com` email.

The reason you're able to see the `outlook.com` email from Graph Explorer is that Graph Explorer is authenticating against their `outlook.com` account. Put another way, Graph Explorer is authenticating `jdoe@outlook.com` against the `outlook.com` tenant, not `yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`.

When a user authenticates against a given tenant, that token only provides access to data within that single tenant. Microsoft Graph does not allow you to cross tenant boundaries.