# Microsoft Graph external user access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an issue with accessing user data with microsoft graph api.

**Context** : I have a web app with a calendar inside for my users. I would like to give the user the possibility to synchronise this calendar with their microsoft calendar. I did the same thing with google calendars and it works well.

**Problem** : I registered an app on azure and setup my code with the correct access to login and get a token from the graph api.
It kinda works but i can only log in with the address i used to create my app on azure.
So lets say my admin address on azure is test@azure.com , then i can log in and access the data i want . But if i try with another address like for example  test@customer.com, then it fails and display this message :

[image]

I keep looking for a way but the Microsoft graph documentation doesn't seem to talk about this problem.
I tried to add the account as an external user, like the message says (and maybe i did it wrong i'm not really sure of this part) but then i can log in but the data i can access doesn't match the data on the account i tried with, as if adding the user as an external user created a "new" user in my organisation.

**What I want** : I would like to be able to access the data of any user that try to log in with a microsoft email (if they accept the permissions of course).

It's my first time using the graph api so maybe i'm missing something simple...

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to set your app registration to "multitenant + personal accounts"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the So thread reference:

When a user authenticates against your tenant, you only have access to the data controlled by your tenant. In other words, if test1@outlook.com authenticates against yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com tenant, you don't gain access to their outlook.com email.

Reason you're able to see the outlook.com email from Graph Explorer is that Graph Explorer is authenticating against their outlook.com account.
In other way, Graph Explorer is authenticating test1@outlook.com against the outlook.com tenant, not yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com.

When a user authenticates against a given tenant, **that token only provides access to data within that single tenant**. Microsoft Graph does not allow you to cross tenant boundaries.

Thanks Hong for the comment, you may also set your app registration to "multitenant + personal accounts"

So Reference: [MS Graph External User 401 Unathorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496537/ms-graph-external-user-401-unathorized)

Comment: I did set it up with multitenant + personal accounts. I checked the "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"  box in the app configuration